# A* vs trees in longest path

Tags: algorithm, tree, a-star

Let T be a tree in which each node represents a state. The root represents the initial state. An edge going from a parent to a child specifies an action that can be performed on the parent in order to change state (the new state will be the child). Each edge is associated with a gain, i.e., I gain something by transitioning from the parent state to the child state.

Moreover, suppose that each path from the root to a leaf node has length Q.

My objective is the one of finding the most promising path of length Q, i.e., the path that guarantees the largest gain (where the path gain is defined as the summation of the gains attached to the edges in the path).

Obviously, I would like to do this without exploring the entire tree, since T could be very huge.

Thus, I thought about applying A*. I know that A* can be used to find the shortest path in a graph, but:

- I don't have costs, I have gains
- I want to find the longest path (actually not the longest in distance from the start node, but the one whose weights, if summed up, give the highest value)
- I have a tree and not a graph (no cycles!)

Eventually, I came up with a set of question that I would like to pose to you:

1. Is A* suitable for this type of problem? Will I find the optimal solution by applying it?
2. Since A* requires to use an (under)estimate of the cost from the current node to the goal in case of shortest path, am I required to look for an (over)estimate of the gain from the current node to the goal and use it as a heuristic?
3. Given a node n in T, my idea was to compute the heuristic h(n) as the summation of the gains achieved by the children of n, which might not be so tight. Do you think there could be a better solution?

EDIT: given a node n in the tree, the gain attached to an edge outgoing from n cannot be greater than a quantity U(n). Moreover, U(n) becomes smaller and smaller as the depth of n increases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heuristic for using A\* to find the path with the highest gain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962516/heuristic-for-using-a-to-find-the-path-with-the-highest-gain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analysis

The reason is as follows. Suppose you assert that a path `P` is optimal, and have not examined edge `e`. I can, without loss of generality, set the gain for `e` to a value greater than the sum of all other gains in the tree. Then your path `P` is **not** optimal.

So any assertion of optimality made before examining all edges' gains is false.

## Conclusion

If no additional information is given about the gains on edges, **you cannot find the optimal path without exploring the entire tree**.

If you had, for example, an upper bound on gain values, you could use A* to more-efficiently find the optimal path and not examine every edge.

---

*Responses to the changes you made to the question after this answer was written are in the comments below. Make sure to review them.*

Comment: I know for sure that the summation of the edges that are outgoing from a node n cannot be greater than a value U(n). Moreover, U(n) becomes smaller and smaller as the depth of n increases (and so do the gains, consequently). Is it sufficient as an upper bound?

Comment: @Eleanore That bound is sufficient. So you should be able to do exactly what you outlined in steps 1, 2, 3 in your question (I checked your reasoning at it seems correct). A* is suitable and will find the optimal solution (given your heuristic is correct). You are correct that the heuristic should be an **over**estimate in this case.

Comment: The part about being able to use A\* and/or using an overestimate heuristic is completely false - that will not work.  Bellman-Ford may work on the negation of the graph, though, since it is acyclic, but will take as long as or longer than a brute-force.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962516) previously asked by OP *(so she already knew the answer...)*.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Care to elaborate on why it is "completely false" and "will not work"? Negate all of the gains, and suddenly you're trying to find a lowest-cost path to a leaf (goal) node from a start node. Each node has a successor function (children of node). Each action has a cost (negated gain). Negate the **overestimate** heuristic that was talked about and you get a underestimate heuristic - which is what typical A* needs.

Comment: @TimothyShields: Dijkstra's and A\* do not work on graphs with negative weights *(and A\* will not work with a negative heuristic)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Add a really large constant `K` to all edge weights. Since all paths in the tree have exactly length `Q`, you've increased the cost of every candidate solution by `K*Q`. So you're still solving an equivalent optimization problem. I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You would add the same `K*Q` to the heuristic.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes, but I am missing a formal proof for the fact that it will not work.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft does branch and bound bring to the same (incorrect) result?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, A* is normally not the right approach to exploring trees. It is for weighted graphs, not trees. If you are exploring a tree you use backtracking. You can make backtracking more intelligent by using heuristics or pruning.